# How can I check if fields are empty on Send Message button?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js

```
<template>

<div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="firstName"  placeholder="Enter your name">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="lastName" placeholder="Enter your last name">
  </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="message">Type Your message</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" v-model="message" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group form-check" v-for="number in numbers" :key="number">
    <input type="checkbox" :value="number.Broj" v-model="checkedNumbers">
    <label class="form-check-label" >{{number.Broj}}</label>
  </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="alert" @click="sendMessage">Send message</button>
</div>
</template>


<script>
  import http from "../http-common.js";
  import userServices from "../services/userServices.js";
  export default {
    data()
    {
      return {
        firstName: null,
        lastName: null,
        message: null,
        numbers: "",
        checkedNumbers: [],
        success: 'You have submitted form successfully'
      }; 
    },
    methods:
    {
      async sendMessage()
      {
        await http.post("/message", {firstName: this.firstName, lastName: this.lastName, message: this.message, numbers: this.checkedNumbers});
        this.$data.firstName = "",
        this.$data.lastName = "",
        this.$data.checkedNumbers = [],
        this.$data.message = "";

      },

      alert() {
          alert(this.success)
          if(event)
            alert(event.target.tagName)
        },

      retrieveNumbers() {
        userServices.getNumbers().then(response => {
          this.numbers = response.data;
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
      }

    },
    created() {
      this.retrieveNumbers();
    }
  }

</script>
```

So I want to add the option of checking input fields when user clicks "Send Message" button. I tried some options but I faield at that. So please I would appretiate if someone would help me. I'm still learning.

I know I have to use v-if and create the method for checking the fields.

So if you would be most kind and help me solve this problem I would be really grateful.

Thank you dev, community <3

Can I please get a concrete answer. Because I'll learn in that way, so please without condescending and "no-answers"

Comment: How about checking it it before you do the http.post request? In the sendMessage function you have access to all the fields it seems like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it manually :

```js
<script>
  import http from "../http-common.js";
  import userServices from "../services/userServices.js";
  export default {
    data()
    {
      return {
        firstName: null,
        lastName: null,
        message: null,
        numbers: "",
        checkedNumbers: [],
        success: 'You have submitted form successfully'
      }; 
    },
    methods:
    {
      async sendMessage()
      {
        if(!(this.firstName && this.lastName && this.numbers)) return;
        await http.post("/message", {firstName: this.firstName, lastName: this.lastName, message: this.message, numbers: this.checkedNumbers});
        this.$data.firstName = "",
        this.$data.lastName = "",
        this.$data.checkedNumbers = [],
        this.$data.message = "";

      },

      alert() {
          alert(this.success)
          if(event)
            alert(event.target.tagName)
        },

      retrieveNumbers() {
        userServices.getNumbers().then(response => {
          this.numbers = response.data;
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
      }

    },
    created() {
      this.retrieveNumbers();
    }
  }

</script>
```

Or you can this usefull library
https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-basic-form

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define a method to check the fields and call that before the HTTP request in the `sendMessage` method.

You can initialize your data as an empty string `""` and have a method like this:

```
validateForm() {
 return this.firstName != "" && this.lastName != "" && this.message != ""
}
```

Update your `sendMessage` method to something like this:

```
async sendMessage() {
  const isFormValid = this.validateForm()

  if (isFormValid) {
    await http.post(....)
    ...
  }
}
```